# Combine 2 seperate date and time columns into one

Tags: 2007, date-time

I have 2 separate columns in a list document library one is date and one is time can they be combined with a calculated column? If so how?

Thanks

Lewis

Comment: Why are they seperate? Would it not be easier to create them together in the first place?